# Getting Started With Real Time Event Scheduling in Java on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I'm working on a project that will record data on real time events using Java on a linux system.
I have all of the HTML scraping stuff down, that's fine, what I need to figure out is the scheduling and management of the tasks.

There are potentially up to forty events occurring each week, at varying times and events can last up to three hours.
I can create and update the calendar of these events at will, my problem is how to:

1. Schedule a process to scrape each event at the right time, and update the schedule if there's a change.
2. Ensure once the scrape process has begun that it stays running for the entire (indeterminate) duration of the event.

Can anyone advise how best to approach this? I'm not sure where I need to start.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the scrape process"? A Linux process or a Java task?

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision. I mean a java process that scrapes the relevant source page for the relevant content and stores it to a database.

Answer (score 1):

> a) Schedule a process to scrape each event at the right time, and
>   update the schedule if there's a change.

If you do not want to use a library, a good starting point for scheduling your tasks can be [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Though you may find [other scheduling frameworks](http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers) useful for your problem out of which [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) can specifically give you a flexibility in how to schedule the next task based on the current schedule execution results; it also provides a *cron* capability so that if your schedule is fixed, you can take advantage of a fixed scheduled calendar.

> b) Ensure once the scrape process has begun that it stays running for
>   the entire (indeterminate) duration of the event.

Assuming that you're using a library for HTML scraping, you don't need to ensure it's running since it will be Java task object initiated from your application.